# Is there a historic reason for why the Balkans are so fragmented?

Tags: political-history, social-history, the-balkans

Is there a historic reason for why the Balkans are so fragmented? Because while I can't name any of the top of my head, I'm sure there are regions that are just as ethnically diverse, but with less fragmentation and animosity between different ethnicities. So why is this the case in the Balkans?

Comment: What is your source for the Balkans being *historically fragmented*? It was unified under the Ottomans for centuries, by the Romans (both East and West) for centuries before that. How is this different from te simple rise of Nationalism through the 19th and early 20th Century?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: It's no more fragmented than Iraq but because it's in Europe, it's a convenient example in western countries of fragmented nations.

Comment: I should add that the current troubles are religious. This is simplistic, but for example you have the Croats, Serbs and Bosnians who for the most part descend from the same people and they speak the same language. Bosnians are largely Moslem and used the cyrillic alphabet though also use the roman one now, Serbs are Orthodox Christian and use the cyrillic alphabet, Croats are Catholic and use the roman alphabet. You get similar things in Iraq with Arabs, Kurds, Sunni, Shia, Arabic, Aramaic with lots of crossovers that aren't consistent.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Unified? Strange wording, i have never heared about the unification of native American tribes by white settlers or the unification of India with the help of British Empire.

Comment: Well, a little help: most Europe has the same diversity of ethical groups, only national movements in Central and Western Europe were more successful in unifications (often a rather bloody way) to larger ethic entities.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on a false premise:

"*I'm sure there are regions that are just as ethnically diverse, but with less fragmentation and animosity between different ethnicities. So why is this the case in the Balkans?*"

Here are the [countries of the Balkans listed by descending area in square kilometres)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_area), with the additional  ***nations* of [England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England), [Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotland), [Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wales), Ireland** and **[Northern Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland)** mixed in for comparison:

- Romania 238,392
- Greece 131,940
- **England 130,279**
- Bulgaria 110,994
- Hungary 93,030
- **Scotland 77,993**
- Serbia 77,453
- **Ireland 70,273**
- Croatia 56,594
- Bosnia & Hercegovina 51,129
- Albania 28,748
- Macedonia 25,713
- **Wales 20,779**
- Slovenia 20,273
- **Northern Ireland 14,130**
- Montenegro 13,812
- Kosovo 10,908

As you can see, the Balkans is no more or less fragmented *nationally* than the British Isles are.

That there has been an undue amount of warfare in the region over the past two hundred years, in the breakup of the Ottoman and Austrian empires that previously ruled the area for a millennium, is comparable to the centuries of bloodshed that led to the independence of Ireland in the early 20th Century, and the unification of England, Scotland and Wales from the 12th to 18 centuries.

Further, the breakup of the Ottoman Empire over the 19th and early 20th centuries coincides with  the rise of *nationalism* throughout most of Europe. The broken nature of the mountainous terrain had fostered a wide variety of 
distinct ethnic-religious cultures that all saw themselves as distinct *nations*, but not always with distinct natural borders. This latter point is particularly true for the religiously distinct but otherwise very similar *Serbians*, *Croats* and *Bosnians*; intertwined territorially and sharing a language with slight dialectal variation.

---

**Update**

A commenter claims that my comparison of the Balkans to the British Isles is clearly inappropriate because:

> *As diverse as the British Islands are, their overwhelming history is not one of fracture but one of unity. Unity of a single powerful country dominating it's internal rivals.*

I counter that the [History of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conflicts_in_Ireland) alone, and of any century of that history from the 11th to the 19th, is more fragmented and ethnically violent than the Balkans has ever seen. It is simply more remote from our present consciousness.

Similarly the main island has seen numerous periods of internecine violence comparable to anything witnessed by the Balkans over a comparable time period:

- In the power vacuum created in the departure of the Roman Empire in the mid 5th century, we see 600 years of successive invasions and internecine strife through Anglo-Saxon invasion of a Celtic homeland, consolidation of the Anglo-Saxon kingdoms, Viking Raids and the conquest by Canute, followed again by Norman Conquest. Bloody conquest of Wales and Scotland follows for another two centuries, during which time the attempts at conquest of Ireland begin.
- In the wake of the unsuccessful Hundred Years War with France in 1453, there follows in quick succession, with intermittent breaks:

  - Three decades of War of the Roses until 1485
  - Decades of religious strife from the divorce of Catherine of Aragon in 1531 through the ascension of Elizabeth I in 1558, including rule by a foreign monarch in the form of Philip II of Spain
  - More religious strife and Civil War, with breaks, from the ascension of Charles I in 1625 through the Glorious Revolution in 1688 and on to the Battle of Culloden and defeat of [*Bonnie* Prince Charlie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Edward_Stuart) in 1746.

Comment: Your contention that the British Isles are as fragmented by history as the Balkans is not really very well thought out.  As diverse as the British Islands are, their overwhelming history is not one of fracture but one of unity.   Unity of a single powerful country dominating it's internal rivals.   It's history is rich and it's achievements are great.   It is not story of a diverse people torn apart by great outside powers, but a history of a strong nation who not only resisted outside powers but conquered great foreign nations who would challenge it.

Comment: In the 19th century potato famine of the 1940's? In the Easter Riots? During the rebellions of William Wallace and Robert the Bruce, of *Bonnie* Prince Charlie and the English Civil War? During Edward I's conquest of Wales? Certainly there have been periods when British history has been domestically tranquil, just as the opposite has also been true. The Balkans were quite tranquil for most of the Ottoman rule.

Comment: Exactly all internal struggles where there was little or no mischief by outside powers.   Internal struggles which were sorted out internally.  The last time Britain was conquered by a foreign power was 1066,  how you could think that equates to the Balkans which has had a new map and new rulers seemingly every few decades during that time escapes me.  Britain's history would equate to the Balkans if you took away the English, placed it at the crossroads of three continents and you placed three Great Empires on it's land boarders who all picked sides.

Comment: You forget 1485 and 1688, both occasions on which a foreign claimant landed and successfully gained the throne from a reigning incumbent: respectively Richard III and James II.

Comment: and failed.   No I didn't forget them.. I said conquered by a foreign power,  not lost a battle or was unsuccessfully invaded.

Comment: Since when were the [King of Spain, Philip II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Spain#After_Mary_I's_death) and the [Stadtholder of the Netherlands William III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England#Glorious_Revolution) and the [Elector of Hanover, George I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_I_of_Great_Britain#Electoral_reign) not *foreign influences*?

Comment: and when did Spain, the Netherlands or Hanover ever Conquer Britain?   Again never said Britain never experienced other great powers.  I said Britain was never conquered by them since 1066.  I said Britain wasn't fractured by them, rather Britain's history is one of confronting and defeating other great powers which rose up against her.  As it did to Spain, Netherlands, France,  etc etc etc.   Not really the same as the history of the Balkins which were playthings to great foreign powers.

Comment: we have a different understanding of what foreign and conquered means.  Henry VII(Tutor) was a "foreign claimant"?   and King James  in 1688 didn't "conquer" Britain, he was next in line of succession.  He was Queen Elizabeth's successor.  He was also ruling scotland at the time,  not France, Spain or Netherlands.

Comment: @JMS: Perhaps another reading of "*History of the English Speaking People*" is in order. Henry VII was Welsh, certainly regarded as foreign by many English nobles. James VI and I was the successor to Elizabeth I; his grandson James II was **deposed** in 1688 by William III, Prince of Orange, a Dutchman, Stadtholder of the United Provinces of the Netherlands and certainly foreign. Philip II was officially [co-monarch with his wife (*Bloody*) Mary I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Spain#King_of_England_and_Ireland) while also King of Spain.

Comment: Welsh might be a foreigner to the English but he's certainly not a foreigner to Britain.  The quote is no foreigner has conquered Britain since 1066 and I think that's trivial history you are certainly aware of.  James II was deposed and replaced by Mary II his DAUGHTER....   and Philip II was co-monarch by marriage not war waged against the British by Spain.

Comment: Eh, the history of the British Isles is the history of English destruction of Celtic culture. The reason Scotland exists is because it started as a Celtic kingdom but by the time it became anglicised it had decided that it wished to remain separate, at least until the merging of the crowns in 1603, made possible because of how similar the lowland Scottish culture had become to the English. The 1549 prayer book riot in Cornwall resulted in the Cornish population being decimated. It was the beginning of the end for the Cornish language. Not fun and games at all for the non-english peoples.

Comment: Could it be that *today* the Balkans appears to *us* more violent than the British Isles because of the intensity (rate) and not the time integral of that intensity over hundreds of years? I have difficulty believing that the murderous intensity (rate) exhibited during WWII between the Ustasha and the Chetniks, or what the Hungarian did at Novi Sad had any parallel 500 years ago if for no other reason but the availability or the lack of modern weapons. The same goes for the industrial scale mass murder committed against Jewish civilians when compared to medieval pogroms.

Comment: @hyportnex: Are you aware of the [St. Bartholomew's Day Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Bartholomew%27s_Day_massacre)? An organized murder across the breadth of France of between 5,000 and 30,000 individuals identified by religious belief, undertaken in a mere 8 hours or so. Or the [massacre following the storming of Magdeburg in 1631](http://www.historynet.com/thirty-years-war-battle-of-breitenfeld.htm) of 25,000 in a few hours?

Comment: you are right: I should have said intensity=murders/(time*area)

Comment: Agreed on the false premise. I think it's quite a pity that you first comment under the Q mentions 'nationalism' but your answer does not. This 'concept' is important for both explaining the historic processes and our current view of the situation. More general the politics of difference/boundaries/identity: ingroup/outgroup, *divide et impera* etc.

Comment: @LangLangC: How's this.